# Should path search order be identical for ::ShellExecute and static CFile::GetStatus() on relative path .EXE name?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, shellexecute, cfile

From within my MFC App, I am doing something like

```
CFileStatus fs;
if (CFile::GetStatus("MyOtherProg.exe", fs))
  {
  // found the file
  ::ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "MyOtherProg.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
  }
```

but the full path to the file found in the static CFile::GetStatus is NOT the one being executed by ::ShellExecute (it has the same name, but is running a different version of "MyOtherProg.exe", in a different folder).

I have tried this on different PCs with the same O/S (Win7 64 bit), with different sets of "MyOtherProg.exe" in various folders.  Neither PC's ShellExecute runs the same one found in the CFile::GetStatus.  One PC always ends up running version 3, another PC always ends up running version 2 (why isn't THAT consistent?).

Note 1: Across the 2 PCs, at least 3 versions are "installed", but NONE of them are installed in the PATH.  Some DO have SHORTCUTS on the Desktop, if that is some undocumented feature.

Note 2: ALL of them are different versions of "MyOtherProg.exe", but installed in different directories.

Note 3: The full path of the one that ends up being run via ::ShellExecute is the same one found when I just type "MyOtherProg.exe" in the Search edit field below the Task Bar's START menu.  But WHY is the one found by CFile::GetStatus NOT the SAME one?  And why on one PC it's version 2, but on another PC its version 3?

Note 4: On both PCs, the resulting search list of the RUN command "MyOtherProg.exe" only shows 1 version (although on one PC, 3 versions are installed, and on the other PC 4 different versions are installed with a fifth one being a "debug" build).  The PC with 3 versions always ONLY lists version 2, the PC with 5 versions always ONLY lists version 3.

Comment: `CFile::GetStatus()` does not search the path, rather it expands the supplied file path using `GetFullPathName()` which simply prepends path with the current working directory and drive (if needed). The resulting path  may or may not exist. If you need to locate a file on the path, use `SearchPath` then use the fully qualified path.

Comment: Whether they *should* be the same or not is a bit of a null question, as you've found they are evidently not. The only thing you can do to ensure that you get the same exe in each case is to resolve the path first, as @William pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `CFile::GetStatus` expands the relative path with the working directory.
- `ShellExecute` looks for the file using the process creation search order. This is described in the `CreateProcess` documentation. As well as the paths listed there, the per-application path is searched.

In short this means that `CFile::GetStatus` alone is simply not suitable for the task you have in mind. You'd have to re-create the shell search.

But why would you do that? The logical thing to is to call `ShellExecute` directly and check for errors. Let it perform the search, because it knows the rules. Since `ShellExecute` has deficient error reporting you should rather call `ShellExecuteEx`.

On the other hand, if you only want to search in the working directory as you do with your current call to `CFile::GetStatus` then use an absolute rather than relative path. I doubt that this is what you want to do but mention it for completeness.

Comment: Which ::CreateProcess parameter does ::ShellExecute's lpFile parameter map into?  It looks like it could map into either CreateProcess's lpApplicationName (first parm) or lpCommandLine (2nd parm), and the rules for "searching" are different.  From the behavior I am seeing from my calls to ShellExecute, it may be lpApplicationName?  Looking at it some more, I think that this is the crux of my question.

Comment: I would expect ShellExecute to pass `lpFile` as `lpApplicationName` and `lpParameters` as `lpCommandLine`.

Comment: _CreateProcess: lpApplicationName ... or it can specify a partial name. In the case of a partial name, the function uses the current drive and current directory to complete the specification;_ I wish the ShellExecute documentation either explained that or pointed to the CreateProcess documentation.  That is what I am seeing (i.e. it does NOT look in the calling process's folder)